# How to create simple timer method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How to create a simple timer method in Ruby that takes an arbitrary function call?

For example:
`time rspec` or `time get_primes(54784637)`

It should still return the result of the function that is passed in (`get_primes`).

The following doesn't quite work:

```
def time block
  t = Time.now
  result = eval(block)
  puts "\nCompleted in #{(Time.now - t).format} seconds"
  result
end
```

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: You realise this kind of functionality already exists in the standard [`benchmark`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more Rubyesque to use a block:

```
def time
  t = Time.now
  result = yield
  puts "\nCompleted in #{Time.now - t} seconds"
  result
end

time { rspec }
```

Comment: I now understand what yield is. (Finally.)

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is already available in Ruby's standard library, in the [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-realtime) module:

```
require 'benchmark'

time = Benchmark.realtime { 10_000.times { print "a" } }
```

Comment: Except it doesn't return the result of the block, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, no I wasn't doing the OPs work for him, just telling him that the time calculation part of his question is already solved for him.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
def time(&block)
  t = Time.now
  result = block.call
  puts "\nCompleted in #{(Time.now - t)} seconds"
  result
end
```